# how to insert a widget to another, if they are from different classes. and how to create a universal function of closing the child widgets?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, widget

this is my code. I can't put label2 to self.main, and I don't know, how to write a generic function code, that would close the child widgets, that can be specified in the arguments.

```
import tkinter


class mainwin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.main = tkinter.Canvas(self.root, width=200, height=400)
        self.main.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.main.config(bg='green')
        self.root.mainloop()


class addlabel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.label2 = tkinter.Label(mainwin.main, height=2, width=50,   text='Hello Noob!!') 
        #can't put on the canvas 'main'
        self.label2.place(x=0, y=50)
        self.exit_button = tkinter.Button(self.label2, text='Exit')
        self.exit.button.bind('<1>', quit_from_widget)

'''
class quit_from_widget:

  def __init__(self):
    # what code should be written here, to quit any child widget.
'''

mainwin()
addlabel()
```

Comment: The call to `addlabel()` at the very end isn't being executed when you think because the earlier call to `self.root.mainloop()` in `mainwin.__init__()` isn't returning until you close the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use:

```
mylist = parent.winfo_children();
```

Then use a for loop and destroy() to close them off

The main reason you can't put the label in is because you are calling mainloop() before addLabel. The program loops through the code and doesn't execute addlabel() until you close the mainwin() function.

secondly, you can't do mainw.main. the class has no reference to that function. instead try adding a parent function to your addlabel like so:

```
class addlabel:
def __init__(self, parent):
    self.label2 = tkinter.Label(parent, height=2, width=50,   text='Hello Noob!!')
    self.label2.place(x=0, y=50)
    self.exit_button = tkinter.Button(self.label2, text='Exit')
    self.exit_button.bind('<1>', quit)
```

Then, when you call the function in mainw class (before the self.root.mainloop() line) you would write:

```
addlabel(self.main)
```

Comment: can you  by the example of my code write, how to do everything? I will be very grateful

Comment: Well I would appreciate if you tried out what I suggested first. What part is giving you trouble?

Answer (score -1):

```
import tkinter

class mainwin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.main = tkinter.Canvas(self.root, width=200, height=400)
        self.main.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.main.config(bg='green')
        self.root.mainloop()


class CustomLabel(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.label = tkinter.Label(self, height=20, width=30, bg='Red', fg='white', text='Hello')
        self.exit_button = tkinter.Button(self, command=self.destroy)

        # pack these widgets into this frame. You can use grid or
        # place, but pack is easiest for such a simple layout
        self.exit_button.pack(side="right")
        self.label.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)



window = mainwin()

label = CustomLabel(window.main)
```

nothing happens. gives green background and the child widget is not visible. but when closing, he writes an error:
....
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "frame" command: application has been destroyed

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: this does not appear to be an answer to the question.